# problem with otel metrics for my python application

Tags: python, grafana, open-telemetry

I am trying to output some metrics for my python application. I am only seeing a few metrics. Using fast api. Logs work fine.

metrics i see in the output when outputting to console

- http.server.active_requests: Measures the number of in-flight HTTP requests.
- http.server.duration: Measures the duration of inbound HTTP requests.
- http.server.response.size: Measures the size of HTTP response messages.
- http.client.duration: Measures the duration of outbound HTTP requests.

Is this what i should expect? I was expecting metrics to be able to populate a dashboard like this https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/19419-opentelemetry-apm/

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a minimal example Python app? It would be helpful to see how you're instrumenting FastAPI.

Comment: I am only doing the auto instrumentation


Including some packages


opentelemetry-instrumentation
opentelemetry-distro
opentelemetry-exporter-otlp
opentelemetry-instrumentation-fastapi
opentelemetry-instrumentation-requests


Running the service like this (Logged to console to see output locally)


CMD ["opentelemetry-instrument", "--traces_exporter", "console", "--metrics_exporter", "console", "--logs_exporter", "console", "uvicorn", "app:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8080"]